# Property is unable to set to nil via weak reference

Tags: swift, memory-management, xcode7, weak-references

The following code defines `Person` and `Apartment`. `Person` instance may own an `Apartment`, `Apartment` may have a tenant(`Person` instance)

```
class Person {
    let name: String
    init(name: String) { self.name = name }
    var apartment: Apartment?
    deinit { print("\(name) is being deinitialized") }
}

class Apartment {
    let unit: String
    init(unit: String) { self.unit = unit }
    weak var tenant: Person?
    deinit { print("Apartment \(unit) is being deinitialized") }
}

var john: Person?
var unit4A: Apartment?

john = Person(name: "John Appleseed")
unit4A = Apartment(unit: "4A")

john!.apartment = unit4A
unit4A!.tenant = john
```

The code snippet above can also be represented graphically as follows. 
[image]

Now the following code is executed to deallocated instance `john`

```
john = nil

if let per = unit4A!.tenant {
    print("\(per.name) is a ghost person") \\This line is prented out, isn't it already a set with `nil`?
} else {
    print("all nil dude")
}
```

[image]

**Problem:** Xcode doesn't set `tenant` property to `nil` (please see the last figure)

**Question**: How can I fix it? I've tried the code on [IBM Swift SandBox](https://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl) and it works well, Xcode has a bug?

Many thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Playgrounds are the work of the devil. Test in a real app project, not a playground, and you will see that this works as you expect.

Comment: Thanks matt, I'll try it.

Comment: Example code here: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk1ch05p254memoryManagement/bk1ch05p254memoryManagement/ViewController.swift Demonstrates the principle identically to what you're doing.