# When exactly are class instances deallocated in the lifetime of a Swift program?

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

Consider the following simple class

```swift
class Person {
  let name: String
  init(name: String) { self.name = name }
  deinit { print("\(name) is being deinitialized") }
}
```

and the following piece of client code

```swift
var john: Person? = Person(name: "John Appleseed")
weak var johnWeak = john
john = nil
print(johnWeak == nil)
for i in 1...3 {
  print("Some other task \(i)")
}
```

I construct a `Person` instance, declare 1 strong reference and 1 weak reference to it. I delete the strong reference, immediately after which the ARC deallocates the instance and sets the weak reference to nil, just as is described in the [docs](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html). I then run some other code. The following is output in the debug area, as one would expect

```
John Appleseed is being deinitialized
true
Some other task 1
Some other task 2
Some other task 3
```

Now I just change the first line of the client. Instead of creating the instance and simultaneously assigning the variable, I first declare the variable annotating its type and then assign it to the new instance

```swift
var john: Person?
john = Person(name: "John Appleseed")
weak var johnWeak = john
john = nil
print(johnWeak == nil)
for i in 1...3 {
  print("Some other task \(i)")
}
```

Now I get an entirely different output

```
false
Some other task 1
Some other task 2
Some other task 3
John Appleseed is being deinitialized
```

For some reason, the instance is not deallocated until the program exits. What is the reason for this behaviour?

Comment: I get the identical (expected) output in both cases, for both Release and Debug build. Just to make sure: You did not test this in a Playground?

Comment: Assuming the test was run in a playground, duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24600008/non-strong-references-not-working-in-playground

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24082011/weak-references-in-swift-playground-dont-work-as-expected

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38397502/property-is-unable-to-set-to-nil-via-weak-reference

Comment: @MartinR Sorry, should have mentioned. Yes, I tested this on Playground.

Comment: @matt I see. So I guess this is a bug with Playground. Strange that they haven't fixed this after 5 years.

Comment: Thanks guys! I can confirm it runs correctly outside Playground. I gotta say though it's pretty annoying, especially since it's supposed to be an environment where you learn the core features of the language.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208323/discussion-between-anar-and-matt).

Comment: Playgrounds are the work of the devil.